# The first email bounces; the second and subsequent emails go through

Tags: debian, email, ipv6, exim

```
550 relay not permitted
```

That's the error message when email sent by Exim4 from my Debian laptop bounces.

What's weird is that only the first email bounces. Second and subsequent emails pass through the relay and on to their destinations just fine. If I reboot my laptop, though, the first email after reboot bounces again.

The relay is plaintext password protected after STARTTLS on port 587. The X.509 certificate is a real one, not a snakeoil. I administer both the relay server and the laptop. The relay server too runs Exim4 on Debian, if it matters. Postfix is not involved.

I suppose that one could work around the problem by configuring the laptop to send a dummy email (or maybe even just an SMTP EHLO?) each time it boots, but the behavior worked around just seems odd. I'm stumped. If you know what I should next investigate to solve this, would you advise me?

Comment: Is the server configured to require fetch before send (i.e. POP before SMTP)?

Comment: @ExUmbris: No, the server is not configured to require fetch before send as far as I know. The server does not fetch. It does run a Dovecot-pop3 service so that Gmail or any other authorized POP3 client can download email *from* the server, but that is just a mailbox action on the server, isn't it? And, anyway, how could the server know that I had rebooted my laptop? Curious.

Comment: timeouts, IPv6 interactions are a possibility. Once I has a similar problem in a server, it turned out to be a strange interaction with the IPv6 local address

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: Investigating your suggestions, I find that there is indeed a timeout. (I had believed that I had ruled out the possibility of a timeout, but your advice has caused me to check again. I was wrong.) So, the problem is probably on the server's end! This is useful to know. Thanks.

Comment: for testing, would this help? `disable_ipv6=true`

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: You are a fine detective. Now that you have told me what to look for, I can see the ipv6 clue in my log. However, if you had not told me what to look for, ipv6 would probably have been approximately the 500th thing I'd have investigated. So far, so good. The `disable_ipv6=true` seems to be working. I'll give it a few days to see whether it continues to work, then I will report back here.

Comment: Have you any public IPv6 addresses, or just public/private IPv4 addresses?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: I would like to have a public IPv6 address, but my hosting provider supports IPv6 less well than IPv4, so I have not ventured to try IPv6. My hosting provider would assign me an IPv6 address if I asked, but then would leave me to figure out what to do on my own. Therefore, regrettably, cowardly, no, I have no IPv6.

Comment: For anyone reading this comment column, `disable_ipv6` is covered in chapter 13 of Exim4's manual, "Starting the daemon and the use of network interfaces" (my version of the manual is 4.84).

Comment: No one is probably reading this deep into the comment column, but I said that I would report back, so here is my report: the solution is still working, thanks. I believe that that solves it.

Comment: I have submitted bug report no. 837535 to Exim4's Debian Maintainer.

Comment: Excellent. I would advise adding the log line you mentioned to your question, so people with the same problem with find it via google.

Comment: It could also be argued it is a feature and not a bug. The current problem is akin to the plug&play problems...The more worrying part is having the decision to prioritise IPv6 traffic e.g. a less tested protocol, to boost IPv6 usage/numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your email timeout could well be due to your daemon trying IPv6 first.

The IPv6 stack implementation *by default* has priority over the IPv4 stack so when programs/daemons try to communicate they will try first to use the IPv6 address, when the destination has both public IPv4 and IPv6 address.

Even if you do not have public IPv6, you have IPv6 localhost and link local addresses.

It would be not the first time, *and probably not the last* time, that I do catch Internet daemons trying first the link local address as source IP address to communicate to another address, and only after timing out, if they still have time/tries allotted, might fall back to sending the data to the IPv4 destination. (In the past, I already had DNS and email problems due to this in an ISP I used to run.)

So for exim, you can disable IPv6 at application/daemon level, using the directive `disable_ipv6=true` in `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template` or `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf` depending on whether you are using the non-split or the split configuration scheme.

From [Exim Internet Mailer-Chapter 14 - Main configuration](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-main_configuration.html)

> disable_ipv6  Use: main   Type: boolean   Default: false
>   If this option is
>   set true, even if the Exim binary has IPv6 support, no IPv6 activities
>   take place. AAAA records are never looked up, and any IPv6 addresses
>   that are listed in local_interfaces, data for the manualroute router,
>   etc. are ignored. If IP literals are enabled, the ipliteral router
>   declines to handle IPv6 literal addresses.

An alternative approach might be also binding it only to IPv4 addresses, *however the disadvantage is having to hardcode the IPv4 address(es) in the configuration*:

```
local_interfaces = <; 127.0.0.1 ; \
                  192.168.23.65
```

As for the system itself, as you are not actively using IPv6:

add as the last line to give priority by default to IPv4, to the file `/etc/gai.conf`

```
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100
```

Add to `/etc/sysctl.conf` to disable by default the IPv6 stack (setting supported from kernel 3 onwards):

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
```

The sysctl will be applied at boot time. To activate it before booting, do:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

Whilst they call it an IPv6 deactivation, the module is still loaded, and while the interfaces do not have IPv6 addresses anymore, you can still see applications connected to their IPv6 sockets. You can also pass to the kernel an option to disable IPv6, and the IPv6 kernel module won't be loaded. Editing `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"
```

And then to apply it, if you have grub (your grub partition may vary or you might not have it; I do not have it in my ARM servers, and have to edit other file for the kernel options):

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

You may have to configure one or other daemon to disable IPv6 at the application level (from the top of my head, `xinetd`, if you have it installed).

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @RuiFRibeiro is the important one. Read that one first. However, once you have understood that answer, here is some additional information that may help.

If your relay host requires that your laptop authenticate itself before relaying mail (which your relay host probably should do), then you should configure Exim4 on your laptop *always to authenticate itself* to the relay server.

The relay server is also known as a "smarthost." Whichever name you call it by, here is the problem. The default behavior of your laptop's Exim4 is [i] to try to authenticate itself before transmitting mail, but, if that fails, [ii] to send the mail unauthenticated.

If it falls through to [ii] on your setup, then your mail will bounce, permanently failing.  Of course, you would think that it would never fall through to [ii], but apparently in your case, sometimes it does.

The fix is in the *transport/30_exim4-config_remote_smtp_smarthost* section of your Exim4 configuration (which on my system is in the file */etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template*).  In this section, look for a stanza that begins:

```
remote_smtp_smarthost:
```

In this stanza, you may discover a line that begins:

```
  hosts_try_auth =
```

Some things will follow the `=` sign, but it is the symbol `hosts_try_auth` that interests you. Change this to read:

```
  hosts_require_auth =
```

Change nothing after the `=` sign.

The effect is to cause outbound mail transfer to fail whenever [i] fails, ensuring that [ii] is never reached. How does this help? It helps because, unlike a failure of [ii], a failure of [i] is *temporary,* not permanent. If you have made the indicated change, then your system will respond to failure by retrying with authentication, never abandoning without authentication. This is the behavior you want.

**HOW TO COMMIT THE CONFIGURATION CHANGE**

Just making the change in the configuration file won't fix the problem.  You have to commit the change using exim4-config, for example by issuing the obscure-seeming but actually important Debian command `dpkg-reconfigure -phigh exim4-config`. I do not know whether it is actually necessary to restart the server after committing the configuration change, but I always restart it. To restart, use the command `invoke-rc.d exim4 restart`. [Incidentally, if you are a beginner, then you might feel more confident rebooting the system to just restart *everything.* I did that too when I was a beginner, so I don't blame you, but rebooting to restart a single service really isn't the Debian way. You're a bit like a rock climber with good ropes and hardware: eventually, you learn when it's appropriate to just trust your equipment. Someday, rather than always rebooting, you should learn to become comfortable with the use of the significant command invoke-rc.d(8).]

If you wish to learn more about the symbol `hosts_require_auth`, consult the detailed specification manual that comes with your Exim4 software.

(For information, I am the OP. When I posted the question, I lacked the answer, but after @RuiFRibeiro oriented me I discovered the information this answer gives.)